# Fetching User-Defined-Field in Customer Acumatica REST-API

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to fetch the user-defined-field that I added in Customer Entity but it's not working. I'm getting this error:
`"message": "An error has occurred.", "exceptionMessage": "The column 'Document_AttributeCWPRODID' is not found in the data set.",`

It is working in Contact entity and SalesOrder

My sample parameter in Contact
`$custom = Contact.AttributeCWCID`

In SalesOrder:
`$custom = Document.AttributeSOID`

Comment: Already tried $custom=Document.AttributeCWPRODID and Customer.AttributeCWPRODID